# Step Failed: SeleniumError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.141.59'

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

```
chromedriver-version: 79.0.3945.36 
google-chrome version:79.0.3945.88 
java version:openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
selenium-standalone-server version:3.141.59
```

1. First will start the google chrome headless in background:

   google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox --no-cache --disable-gpu --disable-dev-shm-usage &
2. Then i start the chromedriver:

   chromedriver --proxy-server=10.0.x.x:yyyy --headless --disable-gpu --nogui --no-sandbox --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors  --start-maximized --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-cache
3. Start the hub:
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
4. Register the node and configure it using the below command:

   java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver,browserName=chrome,version="79.0.3945.88",headless=true,chrome_binary=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://IP:4444/grid/register,browserName=chrome,version="79.0.3945.88",headless=true,chrome_binary=/usr/bin/google-chrome,webdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
5. Then I run the command to execute my cases using 127.0.0.1 as host and 4444 as port

Below is the error message.

```
Step Failed: SeleniumError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_232' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Where am I going wrong,Please suggest ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in error message saying "driver.version: unknown" so i am expecting their would be issue with chromedriver.exe path or versions comparability.